# how to move multiple rows from one Grid View to another | WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `GridView` in which the user can select rows he wants to copy (move it to another grid view). up until now, the user had to select each row one by one. I want to improve the UX by letting the user select multiple rows at once and copy multiple rows.
Is there any way I can do this in an easy way?

[image]

The image shows what i want to do, move the selected rows to the right grid view 
 I am using C# WPF and the data is stored in a Datatable which is linked to the grid view
The code I used for moving one line:

```
DataRowView viewRow = (DataRowView)DBElementGrid.SelectedItem;
DataRow row = selectTable.NewRow();                                                                                                 

for (int i = 0; i < DBElementGrid.Columns.Count; i++)                                                                              
{
     row[i] = viewRow[i];                                                                                                            
}

selectTable.Rows.Add(row);        
for (int i = 0; i < DBElementGrid.Columns.Count; i++)                                                                                                   
{
     selectTable.Columns[i].ColumnName = DBElementGrid.Columns[i].Header.ToString();                                                 
}
selectGrid.DataContext = selectTable.DefaultView;
```

Comment: Use the code that copies one row in a loop for each selected row?

Comment: Are you using MVVM? Show some code and what you have tried.

Comment: @blins I am not building a web application it is a standalone c# programm

Comment: What's the ItemsSource of the right DataGrid?

Comment: @mm8 a datatable

Comment: @clem995 just FYI, MVVM pattern is not strictly for web apps and in fact it is probably the most widely used approach with WPF desktop apps.

Comment: @blins oh ok, good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work provided that the right `DataGrid` (`targetDataGrid`) is bound to a `DataView` that contains the same number of columns as the original one that you select from:

```
DataView dv = targetDataGrid.ItemsSource as DataView;
if (dv != null)
{
    foreach (var selectedItem in selectGrid.SelectedItems.OfType<DataRowView>())
    {
        dv.Table.Rows.Add(selectedItem.Row.ItemArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the selected Items of the dataGrid in case you are using DataGrid. So DataGrid.SelectedItems will give you the selected items which you can set as the items source for the right DataGrid.